# SVNAnt - propget task throwing NoSuchMethodError using SVNKit

Tags: svn, ant, svnant

I am trying to query SVN property values using svnant's propget task but running into problems.

I have written a simple Ant target to update the build file's folder and then query a property:

```
<project name="svntest" default="test">

<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" />

<svnSetting javahl="false" svnkit="true" username="xxx" password="yyy" id="svn.settings" />

<target name="test">
    <svn refid="svn.settings">
        <update dir="." />
        <propget path="file.xml" name="svn:keywords" property="prop.value" />
    </svn>
    <echo message="${prop.value}" />
</target>

</project>
```

My SVN repo is on 1.7.5 and I have svnkit 1.7 which should be compatible.

If I comment out the propget and echo lines, it updates the folder fine.
But when I try to query the svn:keywords property for a specific file I get this error:

**C:\somepath\test.xml:11: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.tigris.subversion.javahl.PropertyData.(Lorg/tigris/subversion/javahl/SVNClientInterface;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[B)V**

I have set the svn:keywords property for file.xml to "value" so this does exist, and committed that.

If I change the propget name argument to look for an SVN property (e.g. "testprop") that doesn't exist, it doesn't fail it just returns "${prop.value}", I assume because the prop.value property is not being set.
If I actually add the custom "testprop" SVN property to file.xml, I get the above error again - so it only seems to happen when it finds a property and attempts to get the value of it.

I have had previous issues trying to use javahl, hence setting this to false and using svnkit instead. However since the update task works I wouldn't have thought the javahl/svnkit binding is the issue.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SVNKit's JavaHL bindings are in a file named `svnkit-javahl16-*VERSION*.jar`. This file can be found under the `lib` directory of the `standalone.zip` downloaded from the SVNKit web site.

This Jar file needs to be on the Ant classpath.

**Edit - Follow-up on 10 January 2014:**

The "missing" method is definitely in svnkit-javahl16-1.7.11.jar:

```
> javap -s -classpath svnkit-javahl16-1.7.11.jar org.tigris.subversion.javahl.PropertyData
...
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.PropertyData(org.tigris.subversion.javahl.SVNClientInterface, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, byte[]);
    Signature: (Lorg/tigris/subversion/javahl/SVNClientInterface;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[B)V
...
```

Somehow, this constructor isn't being found on Ant's classpath.

Run the following commands in a Command Prompt:

```
> set ANT_OPTS=-verbose:class
> ant <= your Ant command line here
```

An avalanche of output will be generated. In this will be buried a line like the following:

```
[Loaded org.tigris.subversion.javahl.PropertyData from file:/...]
```

Let us know what the `file:/...` is on your system. If there isn't an exact match, then see if there are any references to loaded classes with "javahl" in the name.

Comment: Hi Chad, this jar is already on my Ant classpath - I previously added that and all the other jars from the SVNKit standalone zip lib (about 16 in total). FYI *VERSION* as you indicated is 1.7.11.

Comment: Thanks for the tips however I have figured this out.
I am using Ant through Eclipse and in my Ant settings I had the svnkit-javahl16-1.7.11.jar added to the Ant Home Entries but also another "svnjavahl" jar. Removed this and it works fine now.